# How do I write the Partial Sum of this (if it exists)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have a summation (really a whole limit): \begin{equation}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+k^2} \end{equation}
I have thought of the problem by writing out the problem as follows:
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline S_1&\frac{1}{n^2+1^2}\\ \hline S_2& \frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+4}\\ ...& ... \end{array}
My thought progression is the numeration becomes a polynomial and the bottom another polynomial of infinite size. However, I also know that when I take the limit of the partial sum I get the value that converges as follows: \begin{equation} \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}S_n=L \end{equation}
Any thoughts to how I can get $S_n$ because if there is a  pattern I am not seeing it.
##Edit
This is really the original problem:
\begin{equation}\lim_{x\to\infty}x\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}) \end{equation}
I am assuming that this represents this: \begin{equation} \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt \end{equation}
After a couple of suggestions I tried rewriting the preceding as the following:
\begin{equation}\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x(1-t^2+t^4-t^6+t^8-t^{10}+O(t^{12}))dt \end{equation}

Comment: n is just a parameter, and at the end I am taking the limit of it.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Abel summation. It could help you obtain bounds to find the result (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)

Comment: In general, I assuming that rewriting that integral in limits would help me calculate the value because I know its $\pi/2$ I need to prove it.

Comment: There are couple of ways of evaluating the sum: Fourier series, residue theorem, etc. The sum is closely related to the partial fraction decomposition of hyperbolic cotangent, and you can use the formula (see [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.E3)):$$\coth z=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}$$

Comment: $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_p=\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{(k+i n)(k-in)}=\frac i{2n}\sum_{k=1}^p\left(\frac 1{k+in}-\frac 1{k-in} \right)$$

Now, using generalized harmonic numbers and the infinite limit
$$S_p=\frac{-i n \left(H_{p-i n}-H_{i n+p}\right)+\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n^2}$$ Using asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$